# RGB in keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-backlight

Translation:
I bought a generic Exbom G550 keyboard, which comes with RGB, but it doesn't work. The RGBs don't work when the operating system boots up, the key that should turn them on would be scroll lock, but it doesn't work, when I open the bios it works normally, only after the operating system starts that it doesn't work.

PS: The keyboard is supposed to work with Linux.

Comment: Please translate the title of the question into English. Aside from the rules, this will most likely increase the chance of getting an answer, as the people who look through the question list likely don't know what it's about and probably skip it.

Comment: Check out https://itsfoss.com/openrgb/

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; so we can't currently provide much. Your release may have kernel stack options, with the newer/older stack option using later *drivers*, but we currently have been given no clues as to what you're using.